# Programming jQuery UI like ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, class, abstraction

I'm trying to develop an abstraction layer to jQuery UI that allows define Widgets as Objects just like (or similar) to ExtJS. This is the concept:

```
var mydialog = new $.ui.dialog({

modal:true,
renderTo:'body',
title:'The Windows Tittle',
content:'The content of the Window'


});
```

Now I can say:

```
mydialog.show();
```

The first step (i think) was to add a Class creation function to jQuery, this allow to make classes:

```
$.MYNAMESPACE.dialog = $.Class ({

constructor:function(){}

//methods and properties

});
```

And here comes the real problem: What I have to put inside the previous class definition to link the real $.ui.dialog with mine? What I meant is that I don't want to create a new widget, I just want to reuse the code behind predefined jQuery UI widgets in order to create an abstraction layer that allows OOP with jQuery UI.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

have you tried the jquery-ui widget factory?  You might be re-inventing the wheel.js

[slideshow](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide1) on what you get with the widget factory

[official splash page](http://jqueryui.com/widget/) and the [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/)

quick idea what it's doing.  I want a new dialog with some custom events on it

```
//this is instantiating the widget, does not need to be in the same file
$(function(){
  $(".some-selector").miDialog({autoopen:true //because we can});
});
//this is a definition, not an instantiation of the widget. aka, 
$.widget("mi.miDialog" //namespace
  ,$.ui.dialog //inherit from this jquery widget
  ,//start your widget definition
{ options:{autoopen:false,//overwrite parent default option, while still giving instance option to override our definition's override of parent
   someInstanceSafeOption: {why:"not",have:"a",subobject:"option"} },
//underscore functions are 'private' unless you dig into the prototype manually
_create :function(){
//you'll need this function.  guaranteed to run once.
// upcoming version call parent create
this._super(); 
//current version call parent create
$.ui.dialog.prototype._create(this.options);
this.element.addClass("mi-dialog"); //help with custom styling
  this._trigger("created"); //trigger custom events
//register for events here, as _create() will only run once per individual instance

},
_init:function(){
//this will run every time someone calls $('some-selector').miDialog();
//i have yet to use it much
},
publicFunction: function(some, params){
 //this function does whatever you want, and is called $('some-selector'.miDialog("publicFunction", some,params);
},
_destroy: function(){
//clean up after your widget's create function, if needed.
}
```